# NavigationBar 's category works on Xcode9, but doesn't work on Xcode10

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime, navigationbar

I added a category to navigationBar to change backgroundImage, image may be gradient or transparent.

Interestingly, it works on Xcode9, but doesn't work on Xcode10. Does not matter with iOS version.

codes:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (Category)

static char overlayKey;

- (UIImageView *)overlay
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &overlayKey);
}

- (void)setOverlay:(UIImageView *)overlay
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &overlayKey, overlay, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (void)el_setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage
{
    [self initOverlay];
    self.overlay.image = backgroundImage;
}

- (void)initOverlay
{
    if (!self.overlay) {

        [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) + kWindow_StatusBarHeight)];
        imgView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        imgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        [[self.subviews firstObject] insertSubview:imgView atIndex:0];

        self.overlay = imgView;
    }
}
@end
```

use:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar el_setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(kScreenWidth, kWindow_NavigationBarHeight)]];
```

Any Ideas as to why this could be happening?

Comment: I found the array obtained by the method `self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews`, which has a value in Xcode9 and an empty array in Xcode10.

Answer (score 0):

Only need to add a line of judgment statements:

```
- (void)initOverlay
{
    if (!self.overlay &&
        self.subviews.count > 0) {
...
```

Xcode10 is too strange.